# Master Theorem Questions?

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, master-theorem

NOTE: I asked this on mathstackexchange, but didn't get the responses I wanted, thought I should post in CS. Sorry if i did something wrong but i am a newbie.

State the asymptotic (worstcase) runtime found by the master theorem. If the master theorem does not apply state why:

1) $T(n) = T(n/3)$

2) $T(n)= 5T(2n/5) + n$

3) $T(n) = 4T(n/2) +15n^3 + 4n^2 +n+4$

1) For the first one I think the master theorem does not apply because I do not have a $k$-value, is this enough to show that I can't use the master theorem?

2) For the second one I know $a = 5 , b=2/5, k = 1$, so $\log_\frac{2}{5}5 < 1$  so the complexity would be $O(n)$.

3) I don't know how to do, can someone show me?

Can you guys verify whether my answers for 1 and 2 hold true and if possible show me how to deal with 3 if possible using the master theorem?

Comment: For (2), you have $a=5$ and $b=5/2$, not $2/5$, since the MT form you're using is probably of the form $T(n)=aT(n/b)+n$.

Answer (score -1):

For (1), try thinking about the problem without using the Master Theorem. Try plugging in some values and see what you get. That would be much more instructive then checking whether the theorem applies (even if that's what the question asks; it's a stupid question in that sense, since it teaches formulaic thinking instead of "open" thinking).

For (3), the Master Theorem applies for an additive term of the form $\Theta(n^k)$; perhaps that's a more general form than the one you've seen in class, and in this case you can try to show that if instead of $n^k$ you have $\Theta(n^k)$ then the Master Theorem applies just as well. (Use the fact that if $f(n) = \Theta(n^k)$ then there exist $a\geq b>0$ and $N$ such that for $n>N$, $bn^k \leq f(n) \leq an^k$.)